# jQuery Scripts not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that has a table that is using jQuery DataTables.

```
@model IEnumerable<DSPFuelLog.Models.code_AutoMake>

<h3>Auto Make List</h3>
<table id="Auto-Make-Table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-5">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AutoMake)
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-5">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Active)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AutoMake)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active)
                </td>
                @if (!item.Active)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MakeID }) |
                        <a href="#" class="text-info js-automake-activate" data-automake-id="@item.MakeID" data-automake-name="@item.AutoMake">Activate</a>
                    </td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MakeID }) |
                        <a href="#" class="text-danger js-automake-delete" data-automake-id="@item.MakeID" data-automake-name="@item.AutoMake">Deactivate</a>
                    </td>
                }

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

On my main view I call this partial like so:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    @{
        Html.RenderAction("Index", "code_AutoMake");
    }
</div>
```

Here is my script to setup the DataTable:

```
var autoMakeTable = $("#Auto-Make-Table").DataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [2] },
        { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [2] }
    ]
});
```

Now, as you can see on the partial view.. depending on whether or not the item is active or not.. either an `activate` or `deactivate` link will appear.

Here is my script for what happens when I click `deactivate`

```
$("#Auto-Make-Table").on("click",
    ".js-automake-delete",
    function() {

        var link = $(this);
        var autoMakeName = $(this).data("automake-name");
        var autoMakeId = $(this).data("automake-id");

        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to deactivate this auto make?",
            function(result) {
                if (result) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: infoGetUrl + autoMakeId,
                        method: "DELETE",
                        success: function(response) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "@Url.Action("Index", "code_AutoMake")",
                                method: "GET",
                                success: function(data) {
                                    //Here just render that partial view like 
                                    $("#myDiv").html('')
                                        .html(data);//This will empty first then render the new data
                                    $(body).html(response);
                                }
                            });
                            toastr.success(autoMakeName + " successfully deleted");
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            var status = capitalizeFirstLetter(textStatus);
                            var error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                            console.log(error);
                            toastr.error(status + " - " + error.exceptionMessage);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    });
```

Now, this script reloads my table, and the `Deactivate` link becomes `Activate`.. but when I click on the `Activate` link.. nothing happens.. and that link is setup the same exact way as the `Deactivate` link.. so with jQuery & ajax..

So after my table reloads.. the scripts no longer work.

How do I get my scripts to continue working?

Any help is appreciated.

**Script for activate**

```
$("#Auto-Make-Table").on("click",
    ".js-automake-activate",
    function() {

        var link = $(this);
        var autoMakeName = $(this).data("automake-name");
        var autoMakeId = $(this).data("automake-id");

        alert('test');

        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to activate this auto make?",
            function(result) {
                if (result) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: infoGetUrl + "ActivateAutoMake/" + autoMakeId,
                        method: "PUT",
                        success: function(response) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "@Url.Action("Index", "code_AutoMake")",
                                method: "GET",
                                success: function(data) {
                                    //Here just render that partial view like 
                                    $("#myDiv").html('')
                                        .html(data);
                                    $(body).html(response); //This will empty first then render the new data
                                }
                            });
                            toastr.success(autoMakeName + " successfully activated");
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            var status = capitalizeFirstLetter(textStatus);
                            var error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                            console.log(error);
                            toastr.error(status + " - " + error.exceptionMessage);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: Where is the handler for `.js-automake-activate` defined?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan just updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because when you add a new HTML with your javascript code, none of those new HTML has the event logged.

So when you do

```
success: function(data) {
     //Here just render that partial view like 
     $("#myDiv").html('')
          .html(data);//This will empty first then render the new data
     $(body).html(response);
    <over here you need to re-bind the 'click' event to your new html> 
}
```

You've binded your events on your previous html tags, but not your new ones. It does not automatically update the bindings for you. Since you changed your html manually, you need to rebind all your events.

Look at your .on code for both activate and deactivate. See how you referenced #Auto-Make-Table that gets erased and replaced (with your code)? This should not be the point of reference for your .on function.

You should try to reference your #myDiv instead, because unlike #Auto-Make-Table, #myDiv doesn't get replaced and the event stays LIVE throughout your code.

So it should be:

```
$("#myDiv").on("click",
    ".js-automake-delete", //(or activate)
    function() { ... }
```

Comment: so literally copy and paste the click event?

Comment: Ahh that did it! Thank you!

Comment: if you use $(document).on("click", ".js-automake-delete"    you might not have to rebind the event handler